# How can the pop up window for "configure google" or "configure github" layout be changed in meteor?

Tags: meteor, package, user-accounts

I want to add an additional button called "Configure another service" along with already existing buttons  "Save Configuration" and "I'll do this later" in a configuration pop up window for Google/ Github OAuth providers in meteor.

Which file or service-configuration parameter or file can be changed for the above layout of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the content of the popups, you need to modify the HTML template that generates the popup.

In this case, the template is called `_configureLoginServiceDialog`, and it is found in the file `login_buttons_dialogs.html`
 of the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package. `accounts-ui-unstyled` gets added as a dependency when you add any of the `accounts-ui` package variants.

But since the template is in a package, you cannot modify it directly.

What you have to do is create your own version of the accounts-ui-unstyled package (The original is here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled) in your project, then `meteor remove accounts-ui-unstyled`, and `meteor add my-own:accounts-ui-unstyled`.